# Do Attached Cards follow the Swapped Monster when Creature Swap is used?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

Suppose you have cards attached to a creature, and then use [Creature Swap](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Creature_Swap). Do those attached cards follow the monster to the other side of the field?

Answer (score 4):

So I know my comment started this question, and if you want someone else to answer I understand. But here is why I do not think they go with the creature.
The official rules about equip cards:

> These cards give an extra effect to 
>   1 face-up monster of your choice 
>   (**either your own or your opponent’s, 
>   depending on the card**). They remain 
>   on the field after they are activated. 
>   The Equip Spell Card affects only 
>   1 monster (called the equipped 
>   monster), but **still occupies one of 
>   your Spell & Trap Card Zones**. If 
>   possible, place it in the zone directly 
>   behind the equipped monster to 
>   help you remember. If the equipped 
>   monster is destroyed, flipped facedown, or removed from the field, its 
>   Equip Cards are destroyed

Emphasis mine.

So it points out that Equip cards you control can in fact be on monsters your opponent controls. [Creature Swap](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Creature_Swap) only says it gives your opponent control of the creature. Not anything else. In my mind the objects attached to the creature would still be under your control.

Comment: I want to put additional emphasis on "If possible, place it in the zone directly behind the equipped monster to help you remember." which seems to strongly suggest (maybe even explicitly declare) that the card there is ONLY a reminder and nothing more.  Thanks for the clear analysis. I'll link this answer to the other question... in due time. BUT!  I would still like interesting techniques to be put on the other page!  In the mean time, I will give others the opportunity to answer as well, and will choose your answer in a few days if I see nothing more convincing.  Thanks for the input.

Comment: Confirming this. Equip Cards don't move unless an effect specifically makes them move. Whatever happens to the Monster they equip, as long as it remains a legal target, they will remain on the Field in exactly the same Spell/Trap Card Zone they started in. The comment about placing them behind the Monster is only about the Zone you initially choose. If they were mere reminders, they would neither block a Zone nor require you to place them in one (but rather attach to the Monster card itself as is seen, among others, in Pokemon).

Answer (score 0):

any equip cards stay attached to the monster, but stays under your control even if the monster moves to your opponent's field. it only leaves if said so by an effect, the monster leaves the field, or gets set (flipped facedown)